# How do I Fix my update center from displaying error

Tags: 14.04, software-center

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed. I installed some packages due to my netflix not working anymore.

this is the message i get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libnss3-1d: Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.17.1-0ubuntu1) but 2:3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is installed
```

How do I go about fixing this problem?

I tried the following

```
$sudo apt-get -f install
```

and this is what i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libnss3-1d : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.17.1-0ubuntu1) but 2:3.17.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1     is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held   packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I appreciate the help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can try asking apt-get to resolve dependencies with:

```
$sudo apt-get -f install
```